# Page jumps up when scrolling down when resizing window

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, bootstrap-4, console.log

I'm working on my websites responsive design. When I get into the console, and to responsive mode, when I resize my page and scroll down, it jumps right back up. this happens only in one SECTION of my site.

The website is built in one html document divided to sections (show and hide). Only one section is acting this way- the longest section.
I use bootstrap, js, jquery and css for my website if it matters...

Comment: can you provide your  website link or live example ?

Comment: my website isn't published yet...